# How to clip inside a box in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image of many colors. Header is a white box and i need to write text over this box. So what happens is through this box, text is clipped and background is seen through this white box. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code details: html and css.

Comment: Only realistic option for this is to create a header image with the text cut out so that the background can show through.

Comment: You can [use SVG](http://jsfiddle.net/3q28m/); this might make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cab do that with background clip: text, but you have only support in webkit

CSS

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, red,white, blue, pink, yellow, green);
}

h3 {
    background-image: inherit;  
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 80px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

h3:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/bEjxh/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this css code on box:

```
#box_over {background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);}
```

Where is `0.1` there is background opacity. You can increase or decrease opacity.

Comment: I think the point is that the OP wants a solid white header with the text being basically a hole through which the background image is visible.

Comment: then how my text is seen through this white box like a hole inside it?

Answer (score 0):

I got your point! Its simple! You can do this with images.

Imagine there is a background colors, and you simply put another div style with image which contains white background with see-trough text! Use photoshop ;)

And also, check this css3 how to do multiple backgrounds in one div:

```
#box_over{
    background:url(clipped_text.png), url(background.png);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: 2 answers....??? that's the 1st time m watching 1 person posting 2 answers for single question!!